# Is 292229292292 the longest 29-smooth number made of 2's and 9's?

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Is 292229292292 the longest [29-smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number) number made of 2's and 9's?

The factorization is $2^2 7^8*19*23*29$.  Is there a general way to find other numbers of this sort without resorting to brute force techniques?

Comment: What does "29-smooth" mean?

Comment: @UmbertoP. It means the number has no prime factor greater than 29.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number

Comment: $100\ldots 0$ is $10$-smooth and made up of $1$'s and $0$'s.  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For for small fixed $B$, e.g. $B=29$, the number $\Psi(x,B)$ of $B$-smooth integers less than $x$ has [an asymptotic estimate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_number)
$$ \Psi(x,B) \sim  \frac{1}{\pi(B)!} \prod_{p\le B}\frac{\log x}{\log p}. $$
So what were the odds of seeing such a 12-digit number that you found?

Roughly the probability would be $\Psi(10^{12},29) * (2/10)^{12} \approx 0.0002$.  So it seems lucky that such a number exists.  The probability will get exponentially smaller as the number of digits increases, so it seems rather unlikely that you'll find more of these.

Comment: A short, elegant proof is likely impossible, so "highly unlikely, here's why" is good enough.